# How to measure horizontal distance between 2 RGB pixels in Kinect?

Tags: kinect

I understand that I can't map RGB pixels `(x,y)` to real world coordinates `(x,y,z)` in meters since every `(x,y)` coordinate in the RGB space gives a "ray" in the world space. But what I need is simply the horizontal distance between 2 RGB pixels (i.e. only the difference in meters between their `x` coordinates). Is that possible **without having the depth image**?

* I'm not using Kinect's official SDK

Comment: You can't convert from a 2-dimensional space to a 3-dimensional space without some sort of reference point for the third axis. If you attempted the conversion the third axis point would be in the same location for every vector.

Comment: I know. But I don't care about the third coordinate. I only care about `x` (and if I can get `y` that would be nice too)